# How to implement SLDS Notification in Lightning Component inside Site (Lightning out)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds

I would like to show a notification in Lightning component that is acceded via Lightning Out in Site, I cannot use Toast messages. The message that I want to show are on success and on error.

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own toast notifications (via a component). For example, you can grab [this component](https://github.com/fracarma/lightning-toast) and use that as your toast notification. Others have certainly implemented this, too, this is just one of many you can find out there. Or, you can write your own component, as it's basically just copy-paste from the SLDS documentation.

Comment: Thank you master!